# Why use the binomial distribution formula when you can simply divide "n choose k" by the number of all outcomes?

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

The binomial distribution formula seems slower to calculate because we multiply the probability of all success and failure outcomes.

If I want to find the probability of getting at least 7 heads out of 10 fair coin flips, I'd rather multiply "n choose x" (x starting from 7) then divide it by 2^10 since it seems faster to do this then calculate everything in the binomial formula. Both methods have to sum up individual probabilities.

I thought maybe large values of n is better suited for the binomial formula, but the binomial coefficient is still complicated to calculate since something like 50000 choose 500 is a lot.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  What you quoted sounds just like the binomial distribution (though I don't know what "multiply "$n$ choose $x$" means.  Are you just saying that you prefer something like $\frac 1{2^n}$ to $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$?  But they are the same...it's just that if $p$ happens to equal $\frac 12$, then $p$ and $1-p$ coincide so the formula is simpler.

Comment: @Lulu I prefer (10 choose 7)/2^10 + (10 choose 8)/2^10 + (10 choose 9)/2^10 + (10 choose 10)/2^10  to get the total probability of getting at least 7 heads instead of multiplying 10 choose x by the probability of success and the probability of failure. Yes (1−)− for that part. I'm wondering what the advantage of the binomial's longer calculation is.

Comment: @ima_prog  What is the "longer calculation"?  $1/2^{10}$ is exactly $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ in the special case $p=1/2,n=10$.

Comment: Again, all you are saying is that the standard formula is simpler in the special case for which $p= \frac 12$.